# How to compare Month-to-Date to previous Month-to-Date using 'Week Ending' date?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, date

Current SQL Code:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`Week Ending`) = MONTH(`Week Ending`) - 1
         THEN Dollar_Amt 
         ELSE 0 
    END) AS Dollar_Amt_2
```

Sample Table:

```
Week Ending  Max_Dt      Dollar_Amt      
2016-09-03   2016-09-01  10          
2016-09-10   2016-09-01  15          
2016-09-17   2016-09-01  5           
2016-09-24   2016-09-01  30         
2016-10-01   2016-10-01  5               
2016-10-08   2016-10-01  15          
2016-10-15   2016-10-01  10
```

The issue I have is that the previous month is always greater than the current month because the previous month is complete and therefore has more `Week Ending` dates.

I want to compare current Month-to-Date to the previous Month-to-Date, but I am having trouble accomplishing this using dates aggregated at the weekly (`Week Ending`) level.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you have some sample data that we can visualize?

Comment: @James, I updated the sample table.  Please note, I am using a BI tool that does not require me to write out a complete SELECT statement, rather, I just need the logic that limits the previous month's data to be month-to-date.  In other words, today being the 2016-10-11 and having a Week Ending date of 2016-10-15, I would want to limit the previous month's data to be between 2016-09-01 and 2016-09-11 (or as close to this as possible—I understand it might not be exact due to the Week Ending dates).

Comment: Are you able to use time-series, exponential smoothing, or just divide by seven to get a figure for each day, and calculate an average instead? Week ending for month-to-month is very jagged!